# Synthesizing SystemC with Vivado doesn't give desired VHDL signals

Tags: synthesis, systemc, vivado, register-transfer-level

I am writing a project is systemC and i have a couple of `sc_in<bool>` and `sc_out<bool>` to communicate between my modules. When I synthesize the project, in the vhdl code produced each `sc_in` and `sc_out` creates a block of signals like this:

```
valid_in_address0 : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
valid_in_ce0 : OUT STD_LOGIC;
valid_in_we0 : OUT STD_LOGIC;
valid_in_d0 : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 downto 0);
valid_in_q0 : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 downto 0);
valid_in_address1 : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
valid_in_ce1 : OUT STD_LOGIC;
valid_in_we1 : OUT STD_LOGIC;
valid_in_d1 : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 downto 0);
valid_in_q1 : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 downto 0);
```

This is way too complicated as for my hardware design as I only want to have 1 signal declared like this:

```
valid_in : IN STD_LOGIC
```

Declaring a variable as `sc_bit`, I had no problem with the generated VHDL but after I tried using `sc_in<sc_bit>` instead of `sc_in<bool>` in my signals to communicate between modules the project does not compile anymore. If I assign values like this:

```
sc_bit asdf = 0;
```

I get the following message:

> ../../../../source.cpp:67:16: error: conversion from 'int' to
>   non-scalar type 'sc_dt::sc_bit' requested

If I assign values like this:

```
sc_bit asdf = '0';
```

I get the following message:

> ../../../../source.cpp:68:14: error: no match for 'operator=' in
>   '((source*)this)->source::asdf = '0''

Is there any other way to declare I/O signals in SystemC so that after synthesis I will only have 1 `std_logic` signal in VHDL?

The `SC_MODULE` for the source in the testbench goes like this

header file:

```
# ifndef SOURCE_H  
# define SOURCE_H  
# include "systemc.h"

using namespace std;

SC_MODULE(source) {    
    sc_in_clk clk;       
    sc_out<sc_bit > valid_out;           
    void do_cycle();       

    SC_CTOR(source) {        
    {       
        //irrelevant initializations
    }            

    SC_THREAD(do_cycle) {
        //i know sc_thread is unsynthesizable but source is testbench     
        //and i need the signal to be sc_out<sc_bit> to give it as            
        //input in my top function to be synthesized              
    }      
};          
#endif //SOURCE_H
```

cpp file:

```
#include "source.h"          

void source::do_cycle() {          
    valid_out = '0';         
    while(true) {         
        wait(clk.posedge_event());       
    //do different kind of stuff         
    }   
}
```

Comment: Well that is a memory type interface....

Comment: could you share your SC_MODULE?

Comment: @Ifor i know it is a memory type interface but i don't want it to be like that.

Comment: @vermaete if you need any other information please don't hesitate to ask me

Comment: Sorry no experience with Vivados C to Vhdl stuff.  Only used cadences offerings, where you have to explicitly indicate when things are memories.  Surly there are some simple examples with the tool that you can start with...